# Using Spring DAO's NamedParameterJdbcTemplate to process a large data set

Tags: spring, batch-processing, large-data

Using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate, when I execute a query, it retrieves millions of documents. I need to process them all, but they dont have to be loaded in the memory all at once. How can I process the result set in batches without the application having to specify additional query clauses (i.e. without using primary_key in ())

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use any template(SimpleJdbc, NamedJdbc or JdbcTemplate) provided you retrieve data in chunks either using ResultSetExtractor and RowMapper or by using any other pagination technique. you can refer to

[Pagination Using Spring ResultSetExtractor](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/63130-how-to-customize-resultsetextractor)

Answer (score 0):

I would say consider use native query , first order your data and then use some kind of pagination keyword as `TOP, LIMIT, ROWNUM` (depending in your database), to return chunk of data based on pages, bring the information to the application increase the network traffic and I believe databases could do this tasks efficiently.

There is a good spring batch module that allow you do that using

```
<bean id="cmrProcessReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="queryString" value="SELECT cmr FROM CmrRequestEntity cmr where cmr.errorMessage is null and cmr.onThread = 0 and cmr.processed = 0 " />
    <property name="pageSize" value="10" /> 
</bean>
```

But I believe you are not using JPA, so consider use native queries.